# Hash table word count

Tags: java, data-structures

At the following code is the wordCount

```
public List<Link<String, Integer>> countWords(String filename) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = readFile(filename);

        for(String line : lines) {
            line = removePunctuation(line);

            List<String> words = splitLineIntoWords(line);
            for(String word : words) {
                // lowercase the word to count all capitalization as same word
                word = word.toLowerCase().trim();
                if(word.isBlank()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // TODO implement

                // Does this word exist in the hash table?

                // If not, create a new entry with the word as the key
                // and the data is the integer 1 (to represent one instance of the word)

                // If the value does exist, update the node's data to add 1 to the count
                // because another instance of the word has been found
                Link<String, Integer> wordLink = wordMap.find(word);
                if (wordLink != null) {
                    // If the word exists, update the value to add 1 to the count
                    wordMap.insert(word, wordMap.hashFunc(word) + 1);
                } else {
                    // If the word doesn't exist, add the word as a new key with a value of 1
                    wordMap.insert(word, 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

base on the test file below the “a_Christmas_carol.txt “file should contain 4428 unique word

@Test
void testCountWords() throws IOException {
List<Link<String, Integer>> words = wordCount.countWords("a_christmas_carol.txt");

```
    Assertions.assertEquals(4428, words.size(), "a_christmas_carol.txt file should contain 4428 unique words");

    Link<String, Integer> tiny = wordCount.wordMap.find("tiny");
    Assertions.assertNotNull(tiny, "The word 'tiny' should exist");
    Assertions.assertEquals(26, tiny.getData(), "The word 'tiny' should occur 26 times");

    Link<String, Integer> humbug = wordCount.wordMap.find("humbug");
    Assertions.assertNotNull(humbug, "The word 'humbug' should exist");
    Assertions.assertEquals(33, humbug.getData(), "The word 'humbug' should occur 33 times");
}
```

When I run the test file it failed the results shows :
Expected:4428
Actual: 32304

The actual results is wordCount number is too big it goes to 32304, even though when add uniqueword method the wordCount still too big not close to the expected number

Comment: Please give us a complete example (aka [mre]) including a sample for the input file to read (but please don't use the full file with > 32000 words here, reduce it to some minimum amount where you can see the "error"). And also: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Only reading the naming eg `wordMap.hashFunc(word) + 1`, how would count that ? What is `wordMap` ?

Comment: It's a little hard for us to figure out what's going on because you're clearly not using the standard libraries -- `wordMap` is clearly not a `java.util.Map`, and it's not clear what `Link` is supposed to be doing, either.

Comment: Why are you not using Java's standard collection libraries?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `removePunctuation` method works? What about `splitLineIntoWords`? In particular, what happens when `removePunctuation` encounters a word like "that's"? Is it split into two words ("that" and "s")? Why does `splitLineIntoWords` return blank words or words with leading/trailing spaces?